# Jupyter notebook unable to read csv files

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, read.csv

I want to import this CSV file

```
tweets = pd.read_csv('/Users/yoshithKotla/Desktop/canal/Music/wmsrry/wmsrry_only')

print(tweets)
```

But it shows an error like this, the file is in the exact same location as mentioned and I am unable to import the CSV file, I tried this with some other CSV files on the desktop, the error still shows.
There are no duplicate files, or any other files with the same name in a different formats as well. I am not able to figure this out

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-ba5ff0134d9f> in <module>
----> 1 tweets = pd.read_csv('/Users/yoshithKotla/Desktop/canal/Music/wmsrry/wmsrry_only')
      2 
      3 print(tweets)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    608     kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
    609 
--> 610     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    611 
    612 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    460 
    461     # Create the parser.
--> 462     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    463 
    464     if chunksize or iterator:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    817             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    818 
--> 819         self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
    820 
    821     def close(self):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1048             )
   1049         # error: Too many arguments for "ParserBase"
-> 1050         return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
   1051 
   1052     def _failover_to_python(self):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1865 
   1866         # open handles
-> 1867         self._open_handles(src, kwds)
   1868         assert self.handles is not None
   1869         for key in ("storage_options", "encoding", "memory_map", "compression"):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _open_handles(self, src, kwds)
   1360         Let the readers open IOHanldes after they are done with their potential raises.
   1361         """
-> 1362         self.handles = get_handle(
   1363             src,
   1364             "r",

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    640                 errors = "replace"
    641             # Encoding
--> 642             handle = open(
    643                 handle,
    644                 ioargs.mode,

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/yoshithKotla/Desktop/canal/Music/wmsrry/wmsrry_only'
```

Comment: @Taxel pls elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add ".csv" at the end of the address and try.
Example:

```
tweets = pd.read_csv('/Users/yoshithKotla/Desktop/canal/Music/wmsrry/wmsrry_only.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the file is truly a CSV file, and your Mac hide the extension, try give the file its extension of `.csv` back. Something like `wmsrry_only.csv`. Or with it full path `/Users/yoshithKotla/Desktop/canal/Music/wmsrry/wmsrry_only.csv`

Now if you can open it with Number app, it may also be an Excel file.

If you want to be sure, open the Terminal app and get into that directory and run `ls -la` to see the file with its extension and run `file <file>` replace `<file>` with the filename and extension that you found out from the previous command.